# When will the x be equivalent to the y in substitution in beta-reduction?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am learning type theory from the book *Type Theory and Formal Proof*. This is the definition of substitution.

[image: definition]

See the (1b), I can't find an example that the x is equivalent to the y. X and y both are variables, so I think that if y is declared as a variable, the x cannot be equivalent to the y.

Comment: Wouldn't that be (1a)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica But y has been a variable. If we have a variable named y, the condition 'if x is equivalent to y' is true implicitly.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thanks for that, I have known it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1a could also be rewritten as

```
y[x:=N] ≡ N, if x ≡ y
```

x, y, z, ... are just meta variables that stand for concrete variables u, v, w, ... in the language of lambda calculus. In principle, we could insert the same actual variable for the placeholders x and y when applying the definition template to some concrete lambda term, and that's the case when x ≡ y.

1a covers the case where the variable in which the substitution happens is the same as the one which gets substituted, and 1b covers the case where the variable in which the substitution happens is not the one that gets substituted.
In case 1a, the entire variable gets replaced; in case 1b, nothing happens.

Example:

```
(a) (λu.u)(λw.w) >> u[u:=(λw.w)] ≡ (λw.w)   (covered by case 1a)
(b) (λu.v)(λw.w) >> v[u:=(λw.w)] ≡ v        (covered by case 1b)
```

Both substitutions have the form `y[x:=N]`, and in both examples, `N ≡ (λw.w)`.
In (a), `y ≡ u` and `x ≡ u`, so `x ≡ y`: This is case 1a.
In (b), `y ≡ v` and `x ≡ u`, so `x \≡ y`: This is case 1b.

Comment: I don't know the meaning of `v1` and `v2`, I think that there is no substitution. And if x and y may refer to the same object vi, for example, (λx. λy. y)(λz. z) -> (λy. y)[x:=λz.z], when the substitution is in y[x:=λz.z], y cannot be determined that which object it refers, the substitution will stop.

Comment: v1 and v2 are some variables of the lambda calculus language that serve as examples of what x and y could stand for. What do you mean by "I think there is no substitution"? You mean nothing happens in the substitution? Yes, that is what is meant by the second case: If you substitute for a variable that is not the one as the variable in which the substitution takes place, the expression will remain unchanged.

Comment: Your example does not match the case described here. (λy. y)[x:=λz.z] is case 3, not 1b. An appropriate example for 1b would be (λx. y)(λz. z) -> (y)[x:=λz.z] = y.

Comment: I changed my answer to a version without the v variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have understood it !